# Link in Symfony buildForm label

Tags: symfony-2.3

In a form Symfony2, how can I do something like that:

```
->add('contract','checkbox',array(
    'label' => 'Link to <a href="#">my link</a>',
    'required' => true
))
```

with a valid link, and not the html formated ?..

Thank for help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use form customization feature.
Please check this article for more information -http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

By default label content escaped. So you don't get valid html there.

Example of overwrite:

**form_theme.twig.html**

```
{% block form_label %}
{% spaceless %}
        <label {% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ label| trans({}, translation_domain) | raw }}</label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_label %}
```

**template.twig.html**

```
{% form_theme form 'MyBundle:Form:form_theme.html.twig' %}
{{ form_row(form.contract) }}
```